# Close a particular content without deleting from database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am facing  small problem here. here it comes all the output. But if I delete those it will delete from database also. I want to close the content only from html page rather deleting it from database.

I am using javascript of that. Any help will be greatly helpful for me.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My Parse App</title>
        <meta name="description" content="My Parse App">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
        <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/reset.css">-->
        <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">-->
        <!--
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            -->
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script>
        <style>
            /* my CSS here */
        </style>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#45a049">
        <div>
            <form id=post-form>
                <label for="fname">First Name :</label>
                <input type="text" id="post-fname" name="firstname"><br>
                <label for="lname">Last Name :</label>
                <input type="text" id="post-lname" name="lastname"><br>
                <label for="image">Select Image :</label>
                <input type="file" id="post-image" ><br>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </form>
        </div>
        <list id="list-posts" style="list-style-type:circle; width:50%" border="2" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="100" >
        </list>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            /* my JS here */
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=text],
select {
    width: 50%;
    /*align-content:center;*/

    align-self: center;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    margin: 30px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-radius: 4px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
input[type=file],
select {
    /*padding: 20px 5px;*/

    padding-right: -5px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    margin: 20px 10px;
}
input[type=submit] {
    width: 40%;
    /*align-self: center;*/

    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: white;
    padding: 7px 30px;
    /*align:center;*/

    margin: 20px 10px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    text-align: center;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
input[type=submit]:hover {
    background-color: #45a049;
}
div {
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;
    /*background-position: 30px 60px;*/

    position: absolute;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    margin: 80px 500px;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
    left=50%;
    top=50%;
}
```

**JS**

```
Parse.initialize("", "");


var Post = Parse.Object.extend("UpdateDelete");
$("#post-form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var Firstname = $("#post-fname").val();
    var Lastname = $("#post-lname").val();
    var Image = $("#post-image").val();

    var new_post = new Post;

    new_post.set("Firstname", Firstname);
    new_post.set("Lastname", Lastname);
    var fileElement = $("#post-image")[0];
    var filePath = $("#post-image").val();
    var fileName = filePath.split("\\").pop();
    console.log("sumbit for post clicked");

    if (fileElement.files.length > 0) {
        var file = fileElement.files[0];
        var newFile = new Parse.File(fileName, file);
        newFile.save({
            success: function() {
                console.log("Inserted");
            },
            error: function(file, error) {
                console.log("Error");
            }

        }).then(function(theFile) {

            new_post.set("Image", theFile);
            new_post.save({
                success: function() {
                    console.log("Image Saved");
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    console.log("Post Save with file error " + error.message);
                }
            });
        });

    } else {

        new_post.save(Firstname, Lastname, {
            success: function(new_post) {
                console.log("All posted");
                getPosts();
            },
            error: function(new_post, error) {
                console.log("Error" + error.message);
            }
        });

    }
});


// deleting item form list
$("#list-posts").on("click", "#delitem", function() {

    close();
    var id = $(this).attr("href");
    console.log("ID retrieved" + id);
    var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
    var delobj = id;

    query.equalTo("objectId", id);
    query.get(delobj, {

        success: function(delobj) {

            delobj.destroy({});
            location.reload();
            console.log("Object deleted successfully");

        },
        error: function(delobj, error) {
            console.log("error deleting");
        }

    });
});

function showDialog() {
    $("#list-posts").on("click", "#showDialog()", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var x = document.getElementById("myDialog");

        function showDialog() {
            x.show();
        }
    })
}

// Retrieving
function getPosts() {
    var query = new Parse.Query(Post);
    query.find({

        success: function(results) {
            console.log("Retrieving");
            var output = "";
            for (var i in results) {

                var Firstname = results[i].get("Firstname");
                var Lastname = results[i].get("Lastname");

                var id = results[i].id;
                //                     console.log(results[i].get("file"));
                var img = "";


                if (results[i].get("Image")) {
                    var file = results[i].get("Image");
                    var url = file.url();
                    console.log("url:" + url);

                    img = "<img src='" + url + "' style='width:170px;height:170px; margin:20px 10px'/>";
                }
                output += "<li style= 'list-style-type:circle' reversed='reversed' >";
                output += "<h3 id='Firstname' href='" + id + "'>" + Firstname + "</h3>";

                output += "<li style= 'list-style-type:circle' reversed='reversed' >";
                output += "<h3 id='Lastname' href='" + id + "' >" + Lastname + "</h3>";
                output += img;
                output += "<button id='delitem' href='" + id + "' style='display:inline-block; margin:20px 10px'>delete</button>";
                output += "<button  id='mydialog' style='display:inline-block; margin:20px 10px'>User Info</button>";
                output += "<dialog id='myDialog'> This is dialog window</dialog>";

                output += "<button id='modals_close' style='display:inline-block; margin:20px 10px'>Close Info</button>";
                output += "</li>";


                $("#list-posts").html(output);
            };
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("Query Error" + error.message);
        }
    });
}
getPosts();
```

Comment: Describe *what* you want to hide/close. Is it some specific elements?

Comment: You could simply add `display:none` to their css dynamically... They won't show up on page and will stay in database as well.

Comment: I want to show up those results but when someone click close it will close from my page .

Comment: @TirthrajBarot: As I understand correctly. There are two event handlers: one for closing (hiding/removing) an item visually, and one for deleting (deleting from server per ajax as well as hide it visually). But clicking on close triggers delete too. The code does not show why, but it's full of errors and any validation tool screams in agony. A fiddle I created from OPs code did not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

First of all: you iterate through a list of items and create HTML for every item. This HTML contains DOM elements having ID. So a single ID occurs multiple times in your HTML, which it isn't allowed. Use classes instead.

There aren't the same amount of closing `<LI>` tags as opening ones.

I created a fiddle from your supplied code: https://jsfiddle.net/1muc0460/
But since accessing api.parse.com is unauthorized (due to initialize fails, because we need an app-key and a js-id), we can't get pretty far with it.

There are a lot errors in it. Selectors containing special character. There are Function definitions inside function definitions with the same name. Those add event handlers, but are never called (initialized).

I started some fixing: https://jsfiddle.net/1muc0460/1/
But I gave up. I don't know what logic you were trying to go after, so it's pretty hard to repair.
I added a test item as your JS would create, but none of your buttons had any effect.

As soon as you provide proper functional code, I can update this answer.